# Create Linked Server with Insert Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to automatically create a linked server for a server that is added to a ServerControl table.

When I insert a new record in the table I have a trigger that fires with the SQL Instance information and calls a stored procedure to create the linked server.

My issue is that when the trigger fires it is failing because it says `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` cannot be run in a transaction.

Does anyone have a trick or workaround that would allow me to accomplish this task?

Comment: You could mark the rows in the table as 'unprocessed' and have a scheduled job which runs and creates the linked servers and then marks the rows. It might not be instant but it will be automatic

Comment: I would go [with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828468/how-to-execute-ssis-package-installed-in-sql-server-in-trigger) approach